Screen flickering with Steam's Big Picture Mode
I'm experiencing screen flickering in Steam's Big Picture Mode. A post on the Arch Linux CN BBS suggests adding the 'XWAYLAND_NO_GLAMOR=1' variable to the Wayland compositor
(<~/.config/environment.d/envvars.conf> according to the post). However, I couldn't find this file on my system, and adding it didn't resolve the issue. How can I add this variable to the Wayland compositor?

OS: Kubuntu 24.10 x86_64 
Host: Vector GP76 12UH REV:1.0 
Kernel: 6.11.0-9-generic 
Shell: zsh 5.9 
Resolution: 1920x1080 
DE: Plasma 6.1.5 
WM: kwin 
Theme: Breeze-Dark [GTK2], Breeze [GTK3] 
Icons: Papirus [GTK2/3] 
Terminal: konsole 
CPU: 12th Gen Intel i7-12700H (20) @ 4.600GHz 
GPU: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3080 Mobile / Max-Q 8GB/16GB 
Memory: 5500MiB / 31863MiB

